# Refresh a page in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an input field where users input a max of 50 words. For additional content, they paste in the next input field so forth and so on.

At the same point, I'm asking users to save the content and proceed. So on saving, I want to empty all these fields since data is passed to the backend.

I know I can do window.location ="/".

But I was wondering if there is any better approach to solve this?

Comment: Why would you to do that to empty all the fields? I'm not quite following you.

Comment: You can use status for input fields and set that status as empty string after saving.

Comment: When working with inputs in React, you would usually want to tie the input value to a `state`. And once you do that, you can empty the relevant values by simply clearing the state. Refreshing a page is cluncky and is usually a last resort type of thing when it comes to modern web frameworks. If you want to add a sample of your code, I could create an example for you.

Comment: You can do [HTMLFormElement.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) to reset form input values. Of course, having controlled inputs - setting input values through state - would be a correct approach.

Comment: @jperl Because I want to show only a maximum of 10 fields to avoid clunkiness in the UI. Once data is saved, I update users with "your data is saved" and then can start inputting from field 1 again instead of scrolling endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use status for input fields and set that status as empty string after saving.

This is example code.

```
     const [data, setData] = useState(null)

     const handleChange = (field, str) => {
            setData({ ...data, [field]: str });
     }

     const handlesubmit ()=>{

         //Your code
         //after saving
         setData(null)
      }
    
    return(
       <>
           <input type="text" value={data?.input1} onChange={e=>{handleChange("input1", e.target.value)}}/>
           <input type="text" value={data?.input2} onChange={e=>{handleChange("input2", e.target.value)}}/>
       </>
     )
```